# How to Prevent Case Assignment trigger on case updation?

Tags: case, before-trigger, assignment-rules

On updation of case owner based on some condition is changing owner back to default user in support settings, how to prevent this? tried following code on before insert:

```
Database.DMLOptions caseAssignmentRuleOptions = new Database.DMLOptions();
caseAssignmentRuleOptions.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = false;
for(Case newCase : Trigger.new){
   newCaseRec.setOptions(caseAssignmentRuleOptions);                         
}
```

It is still updating to the default owner. please suggest how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure that it is caused by Case Assignment rules executing (and not some other automation)?  The debug log is key here.

If the assignment rules are intended to be invoked, then you need a rule at the top that looks at values on the record and assigns it back to the `current owner` when you don't want the assignment rules to do anything if invoked.

**Or**  ... the reason it goes back to the default user in `Support Settings` is because none of the assignment rules apply based on the values in the record.  Maybe your rules need tuning.

Some orgs have as their last rule, an explicit assignment to say, the Support  Queue so when reviewing the assignment rules, you don't have to be aware of the default user in `Support Settings`

**Or** ..you have the [Assign using active assignment rules checkbox](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333678&type=1) enabled to true on the edit page to always run assignment rules and you might want to disable that for updates

Again, review the debug log entries when you have Workflow `INFO`, `FINE`, `FINER` enabled.

Review the [order of operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) which has assignment rules firing at step 9

Comment: So requirement here is to create a dynamic filter based on which cases via email-to-case will be updated. so we can't set single default criteria in assignment rules. owner values will be dynamic.

Comment: Triggers and before save flows run before assignment rules. Do the dynamic assignment there and set a field Is_Already_assigned __c to true.  Have the first assignment rule check that field and assign "same user" (this is effectively a NOP)